# Intent action "Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION" not working for Android TV

Tags: android, android-tv, android-tvprovider

I want to launch the overlay permission setting screen in Android TV, but "Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION" action is not resolved on Android TV. Please find the code snippet below

```
val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION, Uri.parse("package:$packageName"))
startActivityForResult(intent, 0)
```

Please guide me how to launch the overlay permission setting screen in Android TV.

Comment: do you find some solution

Answer (score 1):

It is a known "bug" and won't be fixed as Google is [moving](https://www.androidpolice.com/2019/03/16/android-q-steps-up-the-fight-up-against-overlay-based-malware/) [away](https://www.androidpolice.com/2019/05/08/google-will-entirely-kill-the-overlay-permission-in-a-future-android-release/) from the OVERLAY permission.

See original bug report: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37121932

Comment: Thanks for the update. Any alternative way to redirect the user to OVERLAY permission screen.

Comment: Most Android TVs simply do not have this permission screen so the user can simply not grant this permission using the device's UI. The only solution left is to guide them in setting it using adb.. I thought this was the case on all Android TVs until recently a user pointed out to me that his TCL tv does have the permission screen.. (have not seen it yet myself)